# Add days to a mysql datetime row

Tags: mysql, date

How can I add 14 days to that: `DATE_ADD(p.since, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)` ?

I want to check if the row p.since is exactly 1 year and 14 days old in MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just nest it to another `DATE_ADD`:

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(p.since, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I think you meant DAY instead of DAYS?